# TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Service Migration - Reporting

Tags: azure-devops

We are planning to migrate from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps. TFS 2015 has reporting part, want to check if we can migrate it to Azure DevOps service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Reports in TFS 2015 are based on MS SQL Reporting Services. Azure DevOps service does not contain Reporting Services. Azure DevOps service contains the following parts:

- [Dashboards, charts, reports, & widgets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops)
- [Power BI integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops)
- [Extend Analytics with OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/quick-ref?view=azure-devops)

In [the migration guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54274) you can find the following:

> Excel reports, SQL Server Reporting Services reports, and SharePoint
>   dashboards are available only in Team Foundation Server and not in
>   Azure DevOps Services.

Comment: Thank you for your info Shamrai.